# How to use this module?

Tags: python, module

I am trying to create a calculator, I have the main program and a module. The problem is the module was taken from the main program and I can't seem to call it in the main program.

```
search = input("Please enter your question")
lst = ["math", "calculator"]
if search in lst:
    f = open('file.txt', 'w')

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

print("Select Operator")
print("1.Add(+)")
choice = input("Enter choice(+ or - or * or /: ")

num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))

if choice == '+':
    result1 = (num1 + num2)
    f.write(' ,''%d' % result1)
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", result1)
f.close
```

Can you guys help me to import and use the code in the main program? Thank you

Comment: Please share minimal examples of both the main program and the module. And describe what error you encounter.

Comment: The main program has nothing but some print functions, I tried to run the module in the main program. I tried to import the module by using: import math. But then I dont' know what to write next

Comment: If the main program has nothing but some print functions, you forgot to put an `import` statement in there. Don't use `math` as the name of your module, that's the name of a Python [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html).

Comment: Consider wrapping the code shown with a function (e.g. `def calculator(): ...`). Then when you import your module: `import my_module; my_module.calculator()`.

Comment: Thank you guys, I finally got it. Thanks for all your help.